# Client-server application for logging running processes

Tags: python, security, server, client

My first client-server application. It's a simple Python script that gets a list of running processes from `Server_1` and writes it to a datetime-named file on `Server_2`, every 5 seconds.

I am planning on refactoring this code into one or two functions, maybe one for securing the connection and one for implementing the logic.

I also know nothing about security best-practices, and I'm looking for some pointers. Any feedback on any aspect of the code is welcome.

````py
import os
import paramiko
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

SERVER_1 = os.getenv('HOST_1') or ""
SERVER_1_PASS = os.getenv('PASS_1') or ""
SERVER_2 = os.getenv('HOST_2') or ""
SERVER_2_PASS = os.getenv('PASS_2') or ""

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(SERVER_1, username='root', password=SERVER_1_PASS)

ssh2 = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh2.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh2.connect(SERVER_2, username='root', password=SERVER_2_PASS)

while True:

    now = datetime.now()
    dt_string = now.strftime("%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%S")

    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("ps -aux")

    processes = stdout.readlines()
    output = [line.strip() for line in processes]

    ftp = ssh2.open_sftp()
    try:
        file = ftp.file(dt_string, "a", -1)
        file.write('\n'.join(output))
        file.flush()
        ftp.close()
    except IOError as e:
        print("Could not write to file")
        print(e)

    sleep(5)
```
````

Comment: Don't use root.  Create another account that just has permissions to do these commands. Also, the loop will be 5 seconds plus the time to execute all the code.  Maybe it doesn't matter.

Comment: @RootTwo does that mean create a new user and put them in a specific group, then modify the group privileges of the directory they operate in? Or what do you mean? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> SERVER_1_PASS = os.getenv('PASS_1') or ""
> SERVER_2_PASS = os.getenv('PASS_2') or ""
> ```

I don't think it's a good idea to pass secrets in the environment - that's too easily read by other processes.  Instead, prefer to hold them in a file that's accessible only by the user.  Since we're using SSH, we even already have such a file (`$HOME/.ssh/config`), though a better choice would be to use public-key authentication.

> ```
> ssh.connect(SERVER_1, username='root', password=SERVER_1_PASS)
> ```

Ouch - why to we need to connect as `root`?  We should have a dedicated user for this, with the minimum level of capability to perform the task.

What does `connect()` do when `SERVER_1` is the empty string (our default if not passed in environment)?  Is that what we want, or should we error out in that case?

Comment: can you expand on having a "dedicated user"? I'm confused: do I create a new user and put them in a group and then modify the group's priviledges? Or do I modify group privildges on the directory I want the new user to work in?

Comment: That's quite a broad topic to expand on (and maybe worth looking over on [security.se] (and perhaps [unix.se]) for ideas on how best to set up a user to run a particular task).  Something you could do with SSH is permit only a particular command to be run, thus denying a login shell even to someone with the correct private key.